# Re-enabling a taskbar on one monitor only in DisplayFusion

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, displayfusion

I have 6 monitors connected to my computer. I use DisplayFusion with the multi-monitor taskbar feature enabled and I disabled the taskbar on 3 monitors.

[image]

Is it possible to re-enabling a taskbar on one monitor only?

The only way I have found to re-enable a taskbar is to click on "Enable All Taskbars", but as the name indicates it enables the taskbar on every monitor:

[image]

I use DisplayFusion 5.0.1 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to re-enable a taskbar on one monitor only in DisplayFusion.